# Magento 2 GraphQL How to update custom row

Tags: php, database, magento2.4, model, graphql

Using Magento 2.4.3 Graphql
Able to get, insert and delete a row from the custom table but unable to update(edit) custom row...

custom endpoints -

```
mutation {
  updateCustomMedia(id:7,
    input: {
      product_sku: "24-WB02"
      image_path: "test1001.jpg"
      description:"hello worldtesttest test test test test 100"
      sort_order: 101
      status: 1
    }
  ) {
    cm {
      id
      product_sku
      image_path
      description
      sort_order
      status
    }
  }
}
```

There is the function

```
    <?php
declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace XYZ\ABC\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use XYZ\ABC\Model\Socialform;
use XYZ\ABC\Api\SocialformRepositoryInterface;

class UpdateCustomMedia implements ResolverInterface
{
    protected $_socialform;
    private $socialformRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \XYZ\ABC\Model\SocialformFactory $socialform,
        SocialformRepositoryInterface $socialformRepository
    )
    {
        $this->_socialform = $socialform;
        $this->socialformRepository = $socialformRepository;        
    }

    public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
    {
        if (empty($args['id'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('"id" value must be specified'));
        }

        if (empty($args['input']) || !is_array($args['input'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('"input" value must be specified'));
        }
        try{
            $socialform = $this->_socialform->create()->load($args['id']);
            $socialform->setData($args['input']);
            $mediaModel = $this->socialformRepository->save($socialform);
            return ['cm' => $mediaModel];
        }catch(Exception $e){
            print_r($e->getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

It is always **inserts new record** instead of **update record**

I knew only that this line - `$socialform->setData($args['input']);` always insert new records

How can we update records using GraphQL???

Comment: can you share your whole code for the resolve function.

Comment: @AfreenSheikh please check now i updated my code